# How to use for loop to insert command line arguments?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, imagemagick

I have files that I'd like to insert as arguments using a batch file. These files are numbered as 'image-1.jpg' 'image-2.jpg' 'image-3.jpg' etc. I'd like to add them all automatically but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's what I was trying to do:

```
montage -mode concatenate^
 FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,8) DO (ECHO "folder 1"/image-%%A.jpg^)^
 -tile 4x2^
 -geometry +0+0^
 montage.jpg
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong, as CMD thinks the `FOR` is part of the command that is executing. Is there a way to embed a `FOR` loop like this?

Edit: If I were to type it by hand, the command should look like this:

```
montage -mode concatenate^
 "folder 1"/image-1.jpg^
 "folder 1"/image-2.jpg^
 "folder 1"/image-3.jpg^
 "folder 1"/image-4.jpg^
 "folder 1"/image-5.jpg^
 "folder 1"/image-6.jpg^
 "folder 1"/image-7.jpg^
 "folder 1"/image-8.jpg^
 -tile 4x2^
 -geometry +0+0^
 montage.jpg
```

Comment: I believe that you'd get a lot more mileage if you were to describe the actual application rather than some simplified artificial scenaria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close; you need to build the string before you use the `montage` command. Also, because you are updating a variable inside of a `for` loop, you need delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /l %%A in (1,1,8) do set files=!files! "folder 1"/image-%%A.jpg
montage -mode concatenate !files! -tile 4x2 -geometry +0+0 montage.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. It works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
For /l %%A in (1,1,8) do montage -mode concatenate "folder 1"/image-%%A.jpg" -tile 4x2 -geometry +0+0 montage.jpg
```

Comment: This just runs the command 8 times and overwrites montage.jpg each time. I need each filename to be in the arguement and then executed all at once, so they are merged properly.

Comment: Well you can't use a for loop for that.

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Comment: You just have to type. This is from Help `montage balloon.gif medical.gif present.gif shading.gif 
 -mode Concatenate  -tile 2x2  montage_array.jpg` http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#concatenate